# Can I create a countdown timer without putting it in the Update function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a countdown script that I'd like to pass a few parameters to but I only know how to use a timer in the Update function and Update does not accept parameters. How can I achieve this without using Update? Is this a proper way to do it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    float seconds;
    float minutes;
    public Text timerText;

    public void startTimer(float m, float s)
    {
        minutes = m;
        seconds = s;

        Update ();
    }

    public void Update () 
    {
        if(seconds <= 0)
        {
            seconds = 59;

            if(minutes >= 1)
            {
                minutes --;
            }
            else
            {
                minutes = 0;
                seconds = 0;

                // Show the time in whole seconds, "f0" removes decimal places
                timerText.text = seconds.ToString("f0");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Mathf.Round (seconds) <= 9)
        {
            timerText.text = seconds.ToString("f0");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: you don't need minutes and seconds, you can turn seconds into minutes and seconds easily. A minute equals 60 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you do need to access the state of the timer at any time, then something like that (albeit with cleaner code and less complicated logic, see my hint on seconds and minutes in the comment) is ok. Basically, accumulate delta time to see how much has passed since the start of your timer.

If you just need to wait until the timer finishes, then there's also `Invoke`.

```
public class MyTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
      public float Interval;
      //Some events go here, maybe, to be fired when the timer changes states?

      public void Restart()
      {
           CancelInvoke("Finished"); //In case it's already running.
           Invoke("Finished", Interval); //Calls Finished() Interval seconds from now.
      }

      public void Finished()
      {
           //Fire your events.
      }
}
```

You may also choose to fire something like a `Tick()` method every X seconds to have access to something like the current elapsed time, but in that case I'd ditch coroutines and just accumulate delta time like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer of Alex M., there's also [InvokeRepeating](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html) method, which is similar to `Invoke`, but calls the target method repeatedly. You can use it like this:

```
void Start() 
{
    InvokeRepeating("Tick", 0f, 1.0f);
}

private void Tick() 
{
   // do some stuff here every second, e.g. accumulate time in some variable
}
```

The second parameter of `InvokeRepeating` is the delay with which the first call to Tick should occur and the third parameter is the repeat period with which the Tick will be called.

If you'd like to insert parameters to a method that is called repeatedly (like every X seconds), you would need to look up [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). They can be used like this:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(DoStuffRepeatedly(float param1, bool param2,..., repeatRate));
}

private IEnumerator DoStuffRepeatedly(float param1, bool param2,..., repeatRate) {
    while(someCondition) {
        // do some stuff here
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(repeatRate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I needed to do in this way:

```
public class GameSetup : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {       
        prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.anyKeyDown || Input.mousePosition != prevMousePosition)
        {
            StartGameTimer();
            timeOutWarning.SetActive(false);
        }
        prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    void StartGameTimer()
    {
        CancelInvoke ();
        Invoke ("ShowRestartWarning", timeUntilRestartWarning);
    }

    void ShowRestartWarning()
    {
        GameObject gameController = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("gc");                 // First, find the GameObject
        CountdownTimer countdownTimer = gameController.GetComponent<CountdownTimer>();      // Then, access the Script in the GameObject
        countdownTimer.startTimer(countdownLength);                                         // Finally, call the Script method                                                      

        timeOutWarning.SetActive(true);
        CancelInvoke ();
        Invoke ("RestartGame", countdownLength);
    }

    void RestartGame()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
        Debug.Log("Game Restarted");
    }
}

public class CountdownTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    float seconds;
    public Text timerText;

    public void startTimer(float s)
    {
        seconds = s;
        Update ();
    }

    public void Update () 
    {
        seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
        timerText.text = seconds.ToString("f0");
    }
}
```